# bulk insert txt error with ROWTERMINATOR

Tags: bulkinsert

Have a `txt` file and have to pass it to `sql`

A bulk insert

```
BULK INSERT table
FROM '\ \ 01cends5 \ TestBulk \ a.txt'
WITH (
DATAFILETYPE = 'char'
FIELDTERMINATOR = '|'
ROWTERMINATOR = '\ n ',
FIRSTROW = 1,
LASTROW = 15
)
```

But it do not take as a final line `ROWTERMINATOR` and probe everything and does not work
`{CR} {LF}{LF}{CR}\ n\ r\ r \ n\ n \ r`

My txt format is:

`0 | 20276708598 | 119302 | 201101 | 000000 | 000000`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like something is wrong with '\r' translation to 0x0A, at least in my case.

http://dbaspot.com/sqlserver-programming/463913-bulk-insert-rowterminator-failing.html#post1509360 demonstrates how to do it with exec and specifying of rowterminator with char() function. It worked for me. Paste of sample code from the link above:

```
DECLARE @bulk_cmd varchar(1000)
SET @bulk_cmd = 'BULK INSERT [GRC].[dbo].[UP_040109]
FROM ''C:\TEMP\up\524.d.0''
WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = '''+CHAR(10)+''',FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\t'')'
EXEC(@bulk_cmd)
```